# Take Json Array data to textbox value

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm making an ajax call like

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:17609/api/Address/" + url2 + "/"+house,
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                 $("#Address").val(data.Line1);
        $("#Town").val(data.Town);
            },
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
        }).done(function() {
            $(this).addClass("done");
        });
```

Im getting a JSON result like so
[{"Line1":"12 Forest Way","Town":"London"}]

how do I take the result and populate my textboxes are just getting undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json result comes as array. So you need to loop through if there are multiple items. if it's a single item then simply

```
 data[0].Town
```

will access the element. Checkout the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ec6m0742/1/).